# What to look for when buying an arranger keyboard / keyboard workstation?

Tags: keyboard

Arranger keyboards / keyboard workstations are very helpful devices that can provide us with a big array of tools like oscillators, samplers, effects, sequencers, and many others.

There are countless options to choose from, and it's easy to get lost if you don't know what and where to look for.

What should we be looking for when buying an arranger keyboard / keyboard workstation? Which are the key differences and highlights?

Comment: jjmusicnotes - as per various meta conversations, JCPedroza has worded this one to ask for what the key functions/differentiators/etc should be - not for a recommendation on which one to buy. We should be able to allow these sorts of questions for digital and analogue music tools as well as for more traditional instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you decide to buy which one of them, you need to classify what are exactly your personal music needs.

Arranger is good for beginner, usually its build-up with light-tuts that easy to use.
In Arranger keyboard you can do such things :
- play a Style musics with many patterns and play your full bands with your own chords
- records your play

ex : yamaha psr(all-series)

Workstation usually used for musical recording and live performance(band). You can patch another resources like midi-devices, DAW software(like nuendo,etc), into its so that you can explore the music as long as you want.

basically workstation are more expensive than arranger, arranger is used by beginner keyboardist, tuts are more realistic in workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely require a stand-alone keyboard arranger?  If you plan on doing most of this work in a place that's near your computer, I think you'll find a much less expensive, more fully featured, and more flexible system by using a MIDI keyboard with software on your computer. That system can also grow with your needs, whereas a hardware keyboard only contains what you get when you buy it.

This is a full list of the keyboards I'm talking about - http://www.guitarcenter.com/MIDI-Keyboard-Controllers.gc#narrowSideBar